# How to create a recovery dvd from the recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've got a laptop with pre-installed Windows 7 and the recovery partition.  The laptop doesn't have a Windows Key sticker on it. I'd like to re-partition it and install Linux, and I don't want to keep the recovery partition: instead, I'd like to create a recovery dvd, just in case I need to bring the laptop back to its initial state.

In Windows 7, there is an option "Create a System Repair Disc", but it asks for the "Windows Installation disk" which I don't have.

So is it possible to create a recovery DVD having recovery partition?

Comment: Not possible with all factory recovery partitions , Dell, HP etc. Just make a disk image of the entire drive.

Comment: The recovery DVD isn't enough to recover your laptop back to it's initial state.  Just download a Windows 7 .ISO that is all you need.  If the laptop came installed with Windows 7, then it must come with a sticker, if it does not the installation isn't likely legitimate.

Comment: "The recovery DVD isn't enough to recover your laptop back to it's initial state" I do it all the time with HP recovery DVD's

Comment: Some laptop manufacturers are putting the Windows sticker under the battery. Did you look under the battery for it?

Comment: @CharlieRB, just checked, but sadly, no sticker. It's Lenovo ThinkPad T520 btw.
Ok, I was hoping it'll be easier, but will look into making a disk image of the entire drive, thanks all.